# How to use uiw/react-codemirror as a react-hook-form field

Tags: react-hook-form, codemirror, react-codemirror

I want to use CodeMirror editor as a field in a form that uses `react-hook-form`. Is there anyone who has done this before and how to register editor values using react hook form `register` method?

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `Controller` component from `react-hook-form` to wrap your `CodeMirror` component. The `Controller` component is designed to work with uncontrolled components, like `CodeMirror`, that don’t expose an `onChange` event. You can use the `Controller` to handle events and updates between `CodeMirror` and `react-hook-form`.

like this-

```js
import { useForm, Controller } from "react-hook-form";
import { UnControlled as CodeMirror } from 'react-codemirror2';
import 'codemirror/lib/codemirror.css';

function YourComponent() {
  const { handleSubmit, control } = useForm();
  
  const onSubmit = (data) => {
    console.log(data);
  };

  return (
    <form onSubmit={handleSubmit(onSubmit)}>
      <Controller
        name="code"
        control={control}
        defaultValue=""
        render={({ field }) => (
          <CodeMirror
            {...field}
            options={{
              lineNumbers: true
            }}
            onChange={(editor, data, value) => {
              field.onChange(value);
            }}
          />
        )}
      />
      <input type="submit" />
    </form>
  );
}
```

Basically, `Controller` wraps the `CodeMirror` component and the `onChange` prop of `CodeMirror` is used to update the form value when the code in the editor changes.